# Why are my transformations concatenating, rather than being replaced?

Tags: ios, swift

Ok, this is weird...

```
func closePageCell(cell : BookPageCell) {

    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity

    if cell.layer.anchorPoint.x == 0 {
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(0), 0, 1, 0)
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -0.7 * cell.layer.bounds.width / 2, 0, 0)
        transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 0.7, 0.7, 1)
    }

    else {
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI), 0, 1, 0)
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.7 * cell.layer.bounds.width / 2, 0, 0)
        transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 0.7, 0.7, 1)
    }

    cell.layer.transform = transform
}
```

The transforms are concatenating here but the syntax is '='

Surely '=' replaces the transform. Why is this working ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the CATransform3Dxxx takes in a transform as a parameter which you are feeding itself into, and returns it back. so each time the method is called it is building up the transform, effectively concatenating them together.

if you replaced the `transform` in the parameter with `CATransform3DIdentity` the behaviour you were expecting would happen